# How to read in a .float file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with brain MRI data and it is .float data.

Do you know how to work with it in python?

with

```
with open('[43x25520].float') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
```

I get:

```
Out[16]:  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-64e280c91de5>", line 2, in <module>
    read_data = f.read()

  File "/home/anja/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in
decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position
2: invalid start byte
```

But I want to work with the floats in the file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: do `print(a.read())` to read from the file

Comment: Without knowledge of the actual file format layout, it is impossible to tell how to properly read it. Once you do know, you'll want to take a close look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html

Comment: Where are these files coming from? Is there any file spec from the detector provider?

Comment: Let us start with the basics: is this file a binary file? By the looks, yes. To tell: try to open it in Notepad, can you read something or is it all gibberish? If it is binary, then you probably need to find a library to decode it, or write it yourself. If it is not, maybe it is easier. Either way, please provide some more details by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60737372/edit) your question.

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(list(open('filename', 'rb').read(20)))`? There is sometimes filetype info in the header. As far as I know, mri data is often written to TIFF and `.float` could be an extension of that with additional header information.

Comment: @Holloway it says: [0, 0, 128, 191, 0, 0, 192, 255, 0, 0, 128, 191, 0, 0, 128, 191, 0, 0, 128, 191]

Comment: So its just a matrix 43x22520 filled with floats.. and I want to handle this matrix in python

Comment: There's a definite 4 byte repeat to it. It could just be a stream of floats with no metadata. Given the file is called `43x25520`, is the file 4389440 bytes?

Comment: it is! @Holloway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming these files are just streams of floats, and they're small enough to fit in memory, the following should work.

```
from struct import iter_unpack

with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as dat:
    # This will give you your data as a 1D array
    data = list(iter_unpack('f', dat.read()))
```

This assumes native endianess. You can change the `'f'` to `'<f'` or `'>f'` if you need to specify something different. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

To convert it to a correctly dimensioned matrix, I'd look at numpy.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(data).reshape(43, 25520) # data from above
print(matrix[2,4523])
```

Comment: Now I see the data yes! But I lost the 43x25520 matrix.. So I want to see data[42,25000] for example. But this gives me: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-de15b6e64d84>", line 1, in <module>
    data[2,4523]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: @Anja, See edit about numpy. (NB, I've not used numpy much so there may be a better way of doing this)